# How to pass Application info to another activity through intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to pass a variable of type **Applicationinfo** to another activity through intent.if possible how shall i pass to another activity,how will i retrieve the data at other activity?
(I obtain application info from **onListItemClick()**).Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to pass a variable of type Applicationinfo to another activity through intent.

Yes, as [`ApplicationInfo` is `Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html). Use [`putExtra()` on your `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29), passing in some key plus your `ApplicationInfo`.

> how will i retrieve the data at other activity?

Call `getIntent().getParcelableExtra()`, passing in the same key that you used for `putExtra()`.

Comment: i used this code at first activity ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
           Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), view_process.class);
           intent.putExtra("app1", app);
           startActivity(intent);how shall i retrieve it at second activity?

Comment: @kjcreations: As I wrote in my answer, `getIntent().getParcelableExtra()`, passing in the same key that you used for `putExtra()`. Given that you chose a key of `"app1"`, that would be `getIntent().getParcelableExtra("app1")`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass data between Intent
Here is simple snippet

**This should be in your ActivityFirst.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, ActivitySecond.class);
intent.putExtra("name", "value");
startActivity(intent);
```

Now you can fetch that data at other hand
**ActivitySecond.java**

```
String strData = getIntent().getStringExtra("name"); //Write exact name which have passed in putExtra()
```